# shortcut of switching between two variants of same layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Does anyone know some shortcut to switch between one layout variant to another variant of same layout android studio while editing xml layout?

for e.g. login.xml(layout) to login.xml(layout-land).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such direct shortcut specified in [Android Studio manual](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html). An easy way would be to use

> Control + Shift + N  (Windows) or Command + Shift + O  (Mac)

Simply start typing the name of the layout and you can open the variant you want to. Not really useful for a project with a few files; but this saves a lot of time when working with a huge project with 50-75 XML files each with multiple layout variants.

Answer (score 0):

Use Control + Shift + tab (Windows)

Comment: This will only open or switch between Open windows and tab.